# Issue with Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled on enable cloud config with master 2.4 version

Tags: spring-cloud-config

i upgraded my spring boot application to master pom 2.4 version and using cloud configs with the property enabled spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled = true, I have db password encrypted in cloud properties so by the time i use the db properties i don't have my encryption framework available, so eventually my application failing with invalid username and password .."i have my own encryption service "

i am looking to see load the cloud config properties after i have my encryption service available, but the spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled makes it load first on application startup, before i upgrade to master pom, i was not using spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled so i didn't had any issue, with adding the property the order of loading changed, so i am running into an issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> so by the time i use the db properties i don't have my encryption
> framework available

Use @DependsOn annotation in the bean that uses the db properties to depend on the encryption framework.